# How do I Implement Atomic Update of Post Metadata?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm building a site in which my logged-in users can "love" and "collect" posts. The number of loves and collects are stored within the post metadata using `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()`.

However it occured to me that such operations may be subject to race conditions and indeed this was confirmed by a [Core Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34304). Unfortunately, the solution povided in that ticket only works for the most trivial of cases (and only for post meta).

Looking at the WordPress Upgrader class, it has methods for [creating](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_upgrader/create_lock/) and [releasing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_upgrader/release_lock/) locks but upgrading WordPress is, in the grand scheme of things, a rare occurence. Is this a suitable and scalable solution for post meta or will performance suffer?

Are there any other and more scalable solutions? The counts are required to be 100% accurate.